# How to convert BigDecimal 0E-8 to a particular double value

Tags: java, android, double, bigdecimal

How to convert exponential value of Big Decimal to double value to 2 decimal places in android ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BigDecimal bd;
double d = bd.doubleValue();
```

Comment: OE-8 does gives only 0

Comment: Double 0 is equivalent to 0.00 (and BigDecimal's 0E-8).  If you're asking how to convert a double to a string with 2 decimal places, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755922/how-to-convert-a-double-to-a-string-with-2-decimal-places