# How to convert a double to a string with 2 decimal places?

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, type-conversion

I'm turning this double into a string so I can display it on a TextView. I want the string to have 2 decimal places using String.format, but I don't know where to put it in this line of text.

```
 Example.setText(Double.toString(dValue));
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: as a side suggestion, don't capitalize your variables, it's confusing and it looks like it's a class.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I do use camelCase but i just changed the name of my variable before copying it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is to use a formatted String and specify the number of decimal points. Lately there's been a trend of suggesting the usage of a `DecimalFormat` instead since it will respect different locales and the usage of commas or points as a decimal separator.

```
//The suggested way lately
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");        
twoDecimals.setText(formatter.format(2.123145));

//The usual way with some caveats
twoDecimals.setText(String.format("%.2f",2.123));
```

I'm pretty sure it could also be done with formatted strings, but hey.. who am I to go against the trend.

Answer (score 5):

`Example.setText(String.format("%.2f", dValue));`

- `.2` means 2 decimal places
- `f` means it's a decimal type

Comment: Thanks for the help! Works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
Example.setText(df.format(dValue));
```